# How to create custom control in leaflet draw for Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I am new to leaflet draw plugin and typescript, so I am looking for the way to extend leaflet draw in order to create a custom control that draw a circle. I saw an example written in JS, but don't know how to properly create a control based on leaflet draw plugin.

I am creating web app based on Angular.
Help to extend control in typescript. There ars libs I am using.

```
"leaflet": "^1.3.3",
"leaflet-draw": "^1.0.2",
"@types/leaflet": "^1.2.9",
```

its code snippet how it can be done in JS

```
 }
/*Class for new polygon shape */
L.Draw.CustomCircle = L.Draw.Circle.extend({
    options: {
        repeatMode: true
    },
    initialize: function (map, options) {
        this.type = 'customCircle';
        L.Draw.Feature.prototype.initialize.call(this, map, options);
    }
});


/*Changes some of the default text for the toolbar buttons*/
L.drawLocal = {
    draw: {
        toolbar: {
            buttons: {
                circle: 'Draw a include circle',
                customCircle: 'Draw a exnclude circle',
            }
        },
        handlers: {
            circle: {
                tooltip: {
                    start: 'Click and drag to include circle.'
                },
                radius: 'Radius'
            },
          customCircle: {
                tooltip: {
                    start: 'Click and drag to exclude circle.'
                },
                radius: 'Radius'
            }
        }
    },
    edit: {        }
};

/*Adds new shape types to the options */
L.DrawToolbar.include({

options: {
        circle: {},
        customCircle: {}
    },
        initialize: function (options) {
    // Ensure that the options are merged correctly since L.extend is only shallow
    for (var type in this.options) {
        if (this.options.hasOwnProperty(type)) {
            if (options[type]) {
                options[type] = L.extend({}, this.options[type], options[type]);
            }
        }
    }

    this._toolbarClass = 'leaflet-draw-draw';
    L.Toolbar.prototype.initialize.call(this, options);
},
    getModeHandlers: function (map) {
        return [
             {
                enabled: this.options.customCircle,
                handler: new L.Draw.CustomCircle(map, this.options.customCircle),
                title: L.drawLocal.draw.toolbar.buttons.customCircle
            },
                             {
                enabled: this.options.circle,
                handler: new l.draw.circle(map, this.options.circle),
                title: l.drawlocal.draw.toolbar.buttons.circle
            },
        ];
    },

    // Get the actions part of the toolbar
    getActions: function (handler) {
        return [
            {
                enabled: handler.completeShape,
                title: L.drawLocal.draw.toolbar.finish.title,
                text: L.drawLocal.draw.toolbar.finish.text,
                callback: handler.completeShape,
                context: handler
            },
        ];
    },

    setOptions: function (options) {
        L.setOptions(this, options);

        for (var type in this._modes) {
            if (this._modes.hasOwnProperty(type) && options.hasOwnProperty(type)) {
                this._modes[type].handler.setOptions(options[type]);
            }
        }
    }
});


var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw();
map.addControl(drawControl);
```

Answer (score 4):

I've had the same need and obviously my search ended into this SO question. I didn't like so much the solution proposed by @TheJSWizard because we are in TS so we should use an "object oriented" approach.

Turns out the solution is pretty simple. Starting from the javascript leaflet tutorial for custom controls I created the following Typescript leaflet custom control class:

```
import * as L from 'leaflet';

export class Watermark extends L.Control {

  onAdd(map: L.Map) {
    let img = L.DomUtil.create('img') as HTMLImageElement;
    img.src = '../../docs/images/logo.png';
    img.style.width = '200px';
    return img;
  }

  onRemove(map: L.Map) {
    // Nothing to do here
  }

  constructor(options?: L.ControlOptions) {
    super(options);
  }
}
```

Then I can use the custom control `Watermark` wherever I create a map in the following way:

```
import * as L from 'leaflet';
import { Watermark } from './leaflet-watermark-control';
...

let myMap = L.map("mapId")setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
new Watermark({position: 'bottomleft'}).addTo(myMap);
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

How i've done it in the past is this way, whether it's the correct way to do it or not, i'm not sure. It works. It doesn't follow the 'angular' way of doing things, but you are using an external library that doesn't follow angular, so you can only be as angular as it lets you.

Of course i've only done a bit for you, but this should get you started. It really is the same as doing it in JS, just you have a typescript class around it this time instead.

```
import * as L from 'leaflet';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-map',
  templateUrl: 'foo.html',
})

export class MapPage implements OnInit {
  public map: L.Map;
  constructor() { }

  public ngOnInit() {
    const config = {};
    this.map = L.map('elementId', config)
    this.addLeafletExtras();
  }

  private addLeafletExtras() {
    L.Draw.CustomCircle = L.Draw.Circle.extend({
      options: {
        repeatMode: true
      },
      initialize: function (map, options) {
        this.type = 'customCircle';
        L.Draw.Feature.prototype.initialize.call(this, map, options);
      }
    });
  }

}
```

Just something to note, if you want to add a callback to something in leaflet, that calls something in your angular code, pass the callback and use .bind(this) with it, this will bind the current angular scope to the callback, and you can then safely call your callback from leaflet but keep it within angular (i hope that makes sense).

Comment: But I can do like you recommended because ts throwing an error: 'Property 'CustomCircle' does not exist on type 'typeof Draw'.'

Comment: Are you importing leaflet-draw? `import 'leaflet-draw';`

Comment: Dependencies won't work if you load them in index.html, unless you declare all the properties as `any` (i don't recommend doing that). What you need to do, for typescript's sake is import all of the leaflet plugins you need to use so that typescript knows they exist. You could also create/find a typing to do that aswell.

Comment: Could you provide some working example, for me its hard to get it. L.Draw won't work, because I have to override many classes. I have no idea how to do it

Comment: What are you overriding that's related to L.Draw? Just add the import to the top of the typscript file

Answer (score 0):

I managed to implement it. Its basically not fully in the was of ts, but works

```
declare var L;
export class Ovverides {
addNewTypes() {
    /*change the draw created event to pass in a featureTypeCode.
       This makes it so that when the draw created is triggered, I can fetch the type shape made and
       append that as a property in the generated GeoJSON*/
    L.Draw.Feature.prototype._fireCreatedEvent = function (layer) {
        if (this.featureTypeCode) {
            this._map.fire('draw:created', { layer: layer, layerType: this.type, featureTypeCode: this.featureTypeCode });
        } else {
            this._map.fire('draw:created', { layer: layer, layerType: this.type });
        }
    }

    /*Class for new circle include */
    L.Draw.CircleInclude = L.Draw.Circle.extend({
        options: {
            repeatMode: false
        },
        initialize: function (map, options) {
            this.type = L.Draw.Circle.TYPE;
            this.featureTypeCode = 'include';
            this._initialLabelText = L.drawLocal.draw.handlers.circle.include.tooltip.start;
            this._endLabelText = 'Release mouse to finish drawing.';
            L.Draw.Feature.prototype.initialize.call(this, map, options);
        }
    });
    /*Class for new circle exclude */
    L.Draw.CircleExclude = L.Draw.Circle.extend({
        options: {
            repeatMode: false
        },

        initialize: function (map, options) {
            this.type = L.Draw.Circle.TYPE;
            this.featureTypeCode = 'exclude';
            this._endLabelText = 'Release mouse to finish drawing.';
            this._initialLabelText = L.drawLocal.draw.handlers.circle.exclude.tooltip.start;
            L.Draw.Feature.prototype.initialize.call(this, map, options);
        }
    });

    /*Modify this function to catch the featureCodeType.  This needs to append to the
    Css class name generated so that I can color them and do other stuff appropriately
    based on custom class in our css file*/
    L.Toolbar.prototype._initModeHandler = function (handler, container, buttonIndex, classNamePredix, buttonTitle) {
        var type = handler.type;
        var target = type;
        if (typeof handler.featureTypeCode != 'undefined') {
            target = type + '-' + handler.featureTypeCode;
        }
        this._modes[type] = {};

        this._modes[type].handler = handler;

        this._modes[type].button = this._createButton({
            type: type,
            title: buttonTitle,
            className: classNamePredix + '-' + target,
            container: container,
            callback: this._modes[type].handler.enable,
            context: this._modes[type].handler
        });
        this._modes[type].buttonIndex = buttonIndex;

        this._modes[type].handler
            .on('enabled', this._handlerActivated, this)
            .on('disabled', this._handlerDeactivated, this);
    }

    /*Changes some of the default text for the toolbar buttons*/
    L.drawLocal = {
        draw: {
            toolbar: {
                actions: {
                    title: 'Cancel drawing',
                    text: 'Cancel'
                },
                finish: {
                    title: 'Finish drawing',
                    text: 'Finish'
                },
                undo: {
                    title: 'Delete last point drawn',
                    text: 'Delete last point'
                },
                buttons: {
                    polyline: 'Draw a polyline',
                    polygon: 'Draw a polygon',
                    rectangle: 'Draw a rectangle',
                    circle: {
                        include: 'Create include circle',
                        exclude: 'Create exclude circle',
                    },
                    marker: 'Draw a marker'
                }
            },
            handlers: {
                circle: {
                    radius: 'Radius',
                    include: {
                        tooltip: {
                            start: 'Click to start drawing a circle include',
                        },
                    },
                    exclude: {
                        tooltip: {
                            start: 'Click to start drawing a circle exclude',
                        },
                    },
                },
                marker: {
                    tooltip: {
                        start: 'Click map to place a site marker.'
                    }
                },
                polygon: {
                    tooltip: {
                        start: 'Click to start drawing a site property',
                        cont: 'Click to continue drawing a site property',
                        end: 'Click first point to close this site property'
                    }
                },
                polyline: {
                    error: '<strong>Error:</strong> shape edges cannot cross!',
                    tooltip: {
                        start: 'Click to start drawing line',
                        cont: 'Click to continue drawing line',
                        end: 'Click last point to finish line'
                    }
                },
                rectangle: {
                    tooltip: {
                        start: 'Click and drag to create a site boundary'
                    }
                },
                simpleshape: {
                    tooltip: {
                        end: 'Release mouse to finish drawing.'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        edit: {
            toolbar: {
                actions: {
                    save: {
                        title: 'Save changes',
                        text: 'Save'
                    },
                    cancel: {
                        title: 'Cancel editing, discards all changes',
                        text: 'Cancel'
                    },
                    clearAll: {
                        title: 'Clear all layers',
                        text: 'Clear All'
                    }
                },
                buttons: {
                    edit: 'Edit layers',
                    editDisabled: 'No layers to edit',
                    remove: 'Delete layers',
                    removeDisabled: 'No layers to delete'
                }
            },
            handlers: {
                edit: {
                    tooltip: {
                        text: 'Drag handles or markers to edit features.',
                        subtext: 'Click cancel to undo changes.'
                    }
                },
                remove: {
                    tooltip: {
                        text: 'Click on a feature to remove.'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    /*Adds new shape types to the options */
    L.DrawToolbar.include({
        options: {
            polyline: {},
            polygon: {},
            rectangle: {},
            circle: {
                include: {},
                exclude: {}
            },
            marker: {}
        },
        initialize: function (options) {
            // Ensure that the options are merged correctly since L.extend is only shallow
            for (var type in this.options) {
                if (this.options.hasOwnProperty(type)) {
                    if (options[type]) {
                        options[type] = L.extend({}, this.options[type], options[type]);
                    }
                }
            }

            this._toolbarClass = 'leaflet-draw-draw';
            L.Toolbar.prototype.initialize.call(this, options);
        },
        getModeHandlers: function (map) {
            return [
                {
                    enabled: this.options.circle.include,
                    handler: new L.Draw.CircleInclude(map, this.options.circle.include),
                    title: L.drawLocal.draw.toolbar.buttons.circle.include
                },
                {
                    enabled: this.options.circle.exclude,
                    handler: new L.Draw.CircleExclude(map, this.options.circle.exclude),
                    title: L.drawLocal.draw.toolbar.buttons.circle.exclude
                },
            ];
        },

        // Get the actions part of the toolbar
        getActions: function (handler) {
            return [
                {
                    enabled: handler.completeShape,
                    title: L.drawLocal.draw.toolbar.finish.title,
                    text: L.drawLocal.draw.toolbar.finish.text,
                    callback: handler.completeShape,
                    context: handler
                },
                {
                    enabled: handler.deleteLastVertex,
                    title: L.drawLocal.draw.toolbar.undo.title,
                    text: L.drawLocal.draw.toolbar.undo.text,
                    callback: handler.deleteLastVertex,
                    context: handler
                },
                {
                    title: L.drawLocal.draw.toolbar.actions.title,
                    text: L.drawLocal.draw.toolbar.actions.text,
                    callback: this.disable,
                    context: this
                }
            ];
        },

        setOptions: function (options) {
            L.setOptions(this, options);

            for (var type in this._modes) {
                if (this._modes.hasOwnProperty(type) && options.hasOwnProperty(type)) {
                    this._modes[type].handler.setOptions(options[type]);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}